# Trouble with UITableViewCell for MoPub Native Ad

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, mopub

I integrated MoPub advertising for my iOS app to run some native ads in my UITableViewController (actually, it's a PFQueryTableViewController because I'm using Parse to load data into the tableView).

Everything is running fine - the console shows that ads are being loaded successfully, and I can see the extra cell in my tableView where the ad should be - the problem is that none of the content for the ad is showing up; I only see a blank cell.

The problem doesn't seem to be from MoPub. I think I'm setting up my cell incorrectly because I can't get ANYTHING to show up there.

I have tried 2 things.

1. Setting up the cell using storyboard. I added a new cell to my UITableViewController and created a new class for it, `NativeAdCell`. I designed IBOutlets and connected them to the class file. 
   The content is loaded through a MoPub function like so:

   ```
   func layoutAdAssets(adObject: MPNativeAd!) {
   adObject.loadIconIntoImageView(iconImageView)
   adObject.loadTitleIntoLabel(titleLabel)
   adObject.loadCallToActionTextIntoButton(callToActionButton)
   adObject.loadImageIntoImageView(mainImageView)
   adObject.loadTextIntoLabel(mainTextLabel)
   }
   ```

The app crashes at the first line with console output `(lldb)`.

2. Adding the outlets programmatically. In the `NativeAdCell` file I add outlets like so:

   ```
   var mainTextLabel = UILabel()
   var titleLabel = UILabel()
   var iconImageView = UIImageView()
   var mainImageView = UIImageView()
   var callToActionButton = UIButton()
   ```

And later setting their frames. 
The content is loaded with the same MoPub function. Now there is no crash, but the ad cell shows up completely blank with no content. Even if I manually set `mainTextLabel.text = "Please show up"` nothing will show up.

The crash when I try to load the IBOutlets makes me think something is wrong with the way I'm linking up the NativeAdCell to the tableView, but it seems like the MoPub SDK should handle this.

Can anybody spot the problem based on this info?

Comment: Did you have any luck with this beyond your answer below?  I'm facing the same issue along with it telling me that the iconImageView is nil

Comment: Nope, I have not been able to get it done with IBOutlets :-/

Answer (score 1):

I achieved this without IBOutlets as follows, it's not well documented so I figured this might help someone out who is looking to use the MoPub SDK with custom cells for native ads

```
//
//  AdTableViewCell.swift
//  Trending-News
//
//  Created by Conor Griffin on 22/07/2015.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Conor Griffin. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import MoPub

class AdTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, MPNativeAdRendering {

    var iconImageView: UIImageView! = UIImageView()
    var titleLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    var mainTextLabel: UILabel! = UILabel()
    var advertIndicator: CGSponsoredLinkLabel! = CGSponsoredLinkLabel()
    var adCorner: CGCornerHighlight! = CGCornerHighlight()

    static func sizeWithMaximumWidth(maximumWidth: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: maximumWidth, height: 100)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        let width = CGRectGetWidth(frame)
        let cellFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: 100)

        iconImageView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.grayColor().CGColor
        iconImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        iconImageView.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80)
        contentView.addSubview(iconImageView)

        titleLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, self.frame.width - 110, 25)
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        mainTextLabel.frame = CGRectMake(100, 35, self.frame.width - 110, self.frame.height - 65)
        contentView.addSubview(mainTextLabel)
        mainTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        mainTextLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(11.0)

        advertIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(100, self.frame.height - 30, self.frame.width - 110, self.frame.height - 80)
        contentView.addSubview(advertIndicator)
        advertIndicator.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(10.0)
        advertIndicator.text = "Advertisement"
        advertIndicator.textColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        advertIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 252/255.0, green: 246/255.0, blue: 220/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        advertIndicator.clipsToBounds = true
        advertIndicator.layer.masksToBounds = true
        advertIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 3

    }

    func layoutAdAssets(adObject: MPNativeAd!) {
        adObject.loadTitleIntoLabel(titleLabel)
        adObject.loadTextIntoLabel(mainTextLabel)
        adObject.loadIconIntoImageView(iconImageView)
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide the CGSponsoredLinkLabel and CGCornerHighlight code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite magical, really, that I forgot to add the subviews to the contentView of the NativeAdCell. `self.contentView.addSubview(mainTextLabel)` etc solves #2.

Not sure how to get this to work with IBOutlets still. It would be a lot easier that way (removes need for programmatic constraints).